# Gradle / Jacoco / SonarQube issues

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm going to put a fat bounty on this as soon as the system permits.

What I'm specifically having trouble with is getting coverage and getting integration tests working. For these I see the uninformative error:

```
Resource not found: com.something.somethingelse.SomeITCase
```

Uninformative because there's nothing to relate it to, nor does it mean much to someone who has none of the context.

Here's other weirdness I'm seeing. In cases where there's no integration tests for a subproject, I see this:

```
JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /dev/build/dilithium/target/jacoco-it.exec
```

Why would I see `target`? This isn't a Maven project.  A global search shows there's no `target` directory mentioned anywhere in the code base.

Then, there's this section of [the documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle):

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        properties["sonar.sources"] += sourceSets.custom.allSource.srcDirs
        properties["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integTest.allSource.srcDirs
    }
}
```

Near as I can tell `sourceSets.integTest.allSource.srcDirs` returns Files, not Strings. Also it should be:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.tests", "comma,separated,file,paths"
    }
```

Note that you get an error if you have a directory in there that doesn't exist. Of course there's apparently no standard for what directory to put integration tests in and for some sub-projects they may not even exist. The Gradle standard would be to simply ignore non-existent directories. Your code ends up looking like:

```
sonarqube {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
    sourceSets.integrationTest.allSource.srcDirs.each { File dir ->

        if ( dir.exists() ) {
            builder.append(dir.getAbsolutePath())
            builder.append(",")
        }
    }
    if (builder.size() > 1) builder.deleteCharAt(builder.size() -1 )

    if (builder.size() > 1 )
        properties["sonar.tests"] += builder.toString()

    properties["sonar.jacoco.reportPath"] +=
            "$project.buildDir/jacoco/test.exec,$project.buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"

}
```

Sonar is reporting no coverage at all. If I search for the *.exec files, I see what I would expect. That being:

```
./build/jacoco/test.exec
./build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec
```

...but weirdly, I also see this:

```
./build/sonar/com.proj_name_component_management-component_proj-recordstate/jacoco-overall.exec
```

What is that? Why is it in such a non-standard location?

OK, I've added this code:

```
properties {
    println "Before: " + properties.get("sonar.tests")
    println "Before: " + properties.get("sonar.jacoco.reportPath")

    property "sonar.tests", builder.toString()
    property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "$project.buildDir/jacoco/test.exec,$project.buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"

    println "After: " + properties.get("sonar.tests")
    println "After: " + properties.get("sonar.jacoco.reportPath")
}
```

...which results in: 
[still running]

Comment: OK, I just figured out that "Resource not found" means that the *.xml results found in build/test-results didn't match something else. IDK what, as yet.

Comment: Did you figure out?

Comment: Indeed, I did. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want any bounty or any points.
Just a suggestion.
Can you get ANY Jacoco reports at all?

Personally I would separate the 2: namely Jacoco report generation and Sonar.
I would first try to simply generate Jacoco THEN I would look at why Sonar can not get a hold of them.

Comment: Jacoco seems to work fine in that it does create all of the *.exec files. I don't know what the extra one is for, though, or where it came from. I also can't be sure what is in them.

Comment: For the record, that was my approach from the start. I can see coverage if I set html in the jacoco plugin but I can't tell if the IT are in there.

Comment: Just a little confused by the last part where you say "...but I can't tell if the IT are in there." Are you getting HTML coverage reports that are viewable and correct?

Comment: Viewable yes. The HTML says that it is covered but apparently doesn't indicate by which test it is covered as far as I can tell. That means I don't know if the IT are in there or not.